# xdvi does not show eps files inline

Tags: eps, dvi, ghostscript, debian

When run from the command line `xdvi` gives the following errors

```
$ xdvi text.dvi 
gs: Unknown device: x11alpha
gs: Unrecoverable error: undefined in .uninstallpagedevice
gs: Operand stack:
gs:     defaultdevice
xdvik: read_from_gs: Connection reset by peer
```

and does not show eps files using debian (sid).  What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `ghostscript-x` must be installed for `gs` to render the images to an `X11` device which apparently how `xdvi` deals with displaying `.eps` files.

This is a simple fix, but the obvious google key-words took me a while to find this.

Comment: For the record, `ghostscript-x` is a Debian package, not a TeX package.